# RLU - What do these codes mean in PRTF DDS after I created a report using RLU?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Here is the PRTF DDS snapshots (with non-code lines excluded)

[image: DDS RLU Codes in SEU PRTF Member]

The Codes are

1. TS
2. FI
3. RI
4. SS
5. CL
6. CP+
7. CP

Also, I found that similar codes exist in DSPF sources as well, like 'EC'

Answer (score 0):

These are comment lines inserted into the source file by RLU so that RLU can persist things that are not normally contained in the printer file source, like attribute values for the CRTPRTF command. They are not part of the DDS printer file source. If you remove these comments, the printer file can still be created and behave as expected, but RLU might drop back to defaults for certain things.

Comment: RDi's Screen Designer and Report Writer uses the same (expanded?) set of codes.

Comment: But I believe they are undocumented as far as public documentation is concerned.

Comment: Okay, this Q is totally out of my curiosity regarding bundling concepts into codes (like abbreviations). 

They are comment lines and I know won't affect code execution and maybe they should get cleaned-up while exiting the RLU/SDA to prevent unnecessary design curiosity. Never tried this on RDi, does it hides them well?

Comment: There is only a little bit in the RDI Screen designer, to record which records belong to which screens. they are all at the end of the source. But they really can't be cleaned up on exit because they might as well not be used at all then. They function as metadata that helps the screen/report designer retain information about screens/reports between starts that otherwise isn't stored in the source.